# Losing post data when inserting into mysql

Tags: php, jquery, wysiwyg

This problem seems very strange to me because it is intermittant. I am going to be detailed so please bear with me.

I have a textarea which is made into a wysiwyg editor with http://redactorjs.com

I am using the click-to-edit feature (http://redactorjs.com/docs/examples/click-to-edit/) and saving the data with an ajax post.

The mysql database field is called 'Info' and is set to type 'blob'.

Now, if i enter the following text into the textarea and press save, it will probably store it fine.

*"Hello my name is greg and i am a very good actor.
I am also a cooking enthusiast who once came 2nd in a cooking competition."*

Then if i click edit and add to it

*"Hello my name is greg and i am a very good actor.
I am also a cooking enthusiast who once came 2nd in a cooking competition. I also like to swim on a thursday morning!"*

I sometimes see that only something like the below will be saved into the db.

*"Hello my name is greg and i am a very good actor.
I am also a cooking enthusiast who once came"*

Then if if edit it again and add the same text back in and save again it saves successfully!?!?

Let me show you some code..

**view.php**

echo the info data

```
<script>
function ClickToEditInfo()
{ 
    var info =  ['formatting', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'deleted', '|',
                    'unorderedlist', 'orderedlist', 'outdent', 'indent', '|',
                    'table', 'link', '|',
                    'fontcolor', 'backcolor', '|', 
                    'alignleft', 'aligncenter', 'alignright', 'justify', '|',
                    'horizontalrule']
    $('#info').redactor({ 
            focus: true,
            buttons: info,
            wym: true,
            fixed: true
    }); 
}

function ClickToSaveInfo()
{
    var html = $('#info').getCode();
    var item = <?php echo $item_id; ?>;

    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "ajax/clickToEditInfo.php",
            data: "item_id="+item+"&html="+html,
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(error);
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#ajax").show();
                $("#ajax").html('<span class="label label-info">Saving info.. please wait</span>');
            },
            success: function(html){
                console.log(html);
                $("#ajax").html('<span class="label label-success">Saved!</span>');
                $("#ajax").fadeOut(1000, function () {
                    $(this).hide();
                });
            }
    });

    $('#info').destroyEditor(); 
}
<?php 
    endif; // end check if user owns item
}
?>
</script>

        <div id="info">
            <?php echo $item->getMainField('info', $item_id); ?>
        </div>
```

**clickToEditInfo.php**

```
<?php 
include_once('../classes/item.class.php');
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

$item_id = $_POST["item_id"];
$html = $_POST["html"];
$user_id = $_SESSION['jigowatt']['user_id'];

if( $item->checkUserOwns($user_id, $item_id) ) : //check user owns item

    $item->clickToEditInfo($user_id, $item_id, $html);

else : // user does not own it
    return false;
endif; // end check if user owns item
?>
```

and

**item.class.php > clickToEditInfo**

```
public function clickToEditInfo($user_id, $item_id, $html) {
    $stmt = parent::query("UPDATE `item_main` SET `info` = '$html' WHERE `item_id` = $item_id AND `user_id` = $user_id");
}
```

Can you think of a reason why the data posted in the DB gets intermittently truncated?

**UPDATE:**

I have found a way to reliably reproduce it.
like i said its a wysiwyg editor.

***"Hello my name is greg and i am a very good actor. I am also a cooking enthusiast who once came 2nd in a cooking competition."***

if i highlight competition and click the hyperlink button and link it to google for example. Press Save and the following is inserted.

***"Hello my name is greg and i am a very good actor. I am also a cooking enthusiast who once came 2nd in a cooking"***

i have edited

```
<?php 
include_once('../classes/item.class.php');
if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

$item_id = $_POST["item_id"];
$html = $_POST["html"];
$user_id = $_SESSION['jigowatt']['user_id'];

if( $item->checkUserOwns($user_id, $item_id) ) : //check user owns item

    $item->clickToEditInfo($user_id, $item_id, $html);

    **echo $html;**

else : // user does not own it
    return false;
endif; // end check if user owns item
?>
```

and the console.log(html) is showing

```
<p>Hello my name is greg and i am a very good actor. I am also a cooking enthusiast who once came 2nd in a cooking
```

so its not posting all the data, something to do with the html tags?

**UPDATE2**

I have done console log on **var html = $('#info').getCode();**
and confirmed that

```
<p>Hello my name is greg and i am a very good actor.</p><p>I am also a cooking enthusiast who once came 2nd place on Come dine with me :)&nbsp;<a href="goggle" target="">link</a>&nbsp;</p>
```

is posted, yet only

```
<p>Hello my name is greg and i am a very good actor.</p><p>I am also a cooking enthusiast who once came 2nd place on Come dine with me :)
```

is received in clickToEditInfo.php

how do i fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that data you save is not bigger than max size that column can contain?

Comment: Are data truncated in the Php ?

Comment: @PLB "Then if if edit it again and add the same text back in and save again it saves successfully"

Comment: @PLB its set to blob (A BLOB or TEXT column with a maximum length of 65535). And like i said i can store much more data if i simply retry after the truncate problem occurs

Comment: Enable query log and see there what happens.

Comment: `if( $item->checkUserOwns($user_id, $item_id) ) : //check user owns item

    $item->clickToEditInfo($user_id, $item_id, $html);

else : // user does not own it
    return false;` 

Is this an edit only issue? Does this work when you insert a new text?

Comment: @VinceLowe Check what do you get in `$_POST`. so you'll know where problem is.

Comment: i have seen it when inserting once, then i edited it successfully. Very strange.

Comment: suppose i nned to validate var html = $('#info').getCode(); is working

Comment: guys, just noticed something. updating post in a sec

Comment: Is it the way i am posting the data via ajax? - data: "item_id="+item+"&html="+html,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the post data before sending it over POST

```
var html = escape($('#info').getCode());
```

Comment: Maybe try var html = escape($('#info').getCode());

Comment: oh just did this before i saw your comment, please update your answer for an accept :) cheers

Comment: Nice to see you sorted it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Think i may have fixed it with escape() on the html before i post it.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp

```
var html = $('#info').getCode();
    var item = <?php echo $item_id; ?>;
    var html = escape(html);
```